# Code::Blocks does not work and return a error

Tags: c++, runtime-error, codeblocks, sdl-2

I'm trying to get the SDL2 library to work in C++. After testing the installation (fighting the linker and debugger again and again...;), I managed to run the following code without fatal errors:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) return 1;

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

But at the end, the program returns the integer 32762 with this sentence:

```
Process return 32762 (0x7FFA)
```

and I don't understand why it doesn't just return 0 or 1. Even if I don't have errors or warnings, the program does not operate normally. Honestly, I'm racking my brains about this problem, and Google hasn't helped me much. However, I tried to remove the first line of my code, with the include and the program returns 0. It's as if the SDL2 header is bugging my code and crashing the program... I admit that any help is welcome ! Thank you very much for giving me time.

Comment: Run your program by double-clicking it in the explorer, rather than from the IDE. Show us any errors you get this way.

Comment: Or better, open a terminal and run in from the command line. Your code compiles and runs fine when compiled with either C or C++, returning `0` as it should. With *Full-Warnings Enabled*, you should only expect two warnings `"unused parameter ‘argc’"` and `"unused parameter ‘argv’"`. (which you can eliminate with `int main(void)`)

Comment: Code::Blocks is not the issue here. 
 Code::Blocks is just an IDE, it has no influence on the execution of the code built within it by the _toolchain_ (compiler/linker).  Step the code in the debugger. My bet is that it will terminate before `SDL_Init()` returns.  The debugger may provide information on the cause.  Or the code you are running is not built from the source shown.  Again stepping the debugger may make that clear.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin From my experience, various "DLL not found" errors don't show up in the Windows terminal. That's why I recommend the explorer.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - Ah, I see, I'll have to defer to  your windows wisdom. I have a few installs and keep CodeBlocks and VS for use, but 99.9% of everything I do is on Linux, and has been for 20+ years. So for corner-case and sporadic behavior I happily defer.

Comment: Ok thanks very much for all yours answers. I will clarify my problem. My objective was to compile in satic mode with SDL2, but the result didn't work under Windows who said : "This program can not be run in this PC". So, I left Code::Blocks to go in command line interpreter where I used MinGW directly. Thus, I discorvered that he was him that produce an errors. After many experimentations, I sucessed to provides a good executable in dynamic mode and it finally works. The question should be now : how to compile SDL2 in STATIC mode ?? (Sorry if there is a language errors...)